# Update field in Firebase with condition

Tags: java, android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I have this structure of Firebase, and I am trying to update the Author in all post-comments when the user updates his nick_name. 
I used this query in Android but it didn't fetch all the data that I need:

```
 mDatabase = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference("DataBase").child("post-comments");
            Query query = mDatabase.orderByChild("uid");
```

and down here you will find a picture of the Firebase structure:

[image]

Comment: whats the problem

Comment: I am not getting the data correctly. It only returns the outer keys values, and it doesn't return the actual notes for each comment.

Comment: @Ali you have to traverse throw the second last key, just right now you are just at the second last node.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As I understand from your comments, you trying to change the named of this node `-KykDRTQ5GToIe6oh_kA` to `commentID`. The short answer is **no**, there is no way in which you can change the names of the nodes from your Firebase database. There is no API for doing that. What can you do instead is to attach a listener on that particular node and get the `DataSnapshot` object. Having that data, you can write it in another place using another name. In the end just remove the old node. So you cannot simply rename `-KykDRTQ5GToIe6oh_kA` to `commentID`.

Comment: Hi Ali! Is there everything alright, can I help you with other informations?

Comment: Thank you for your answer. My goal is to update all comments and post with the new Nickname Incase the user change/update his nickname. Snapdata was my first solution by I don’t need to sacrifice with the performance. As the snapdata required two nested for loop inside to get each comment in each post ID. So I thought to use a query instead of two loops inside.

Comment: To update the Nickname with a new Nickname, you said right, you need to to use two nested for loops. This is how it works in case of your database structure. Note, there is no problem regarding nested loops when it comes to Firebase. I recommend you go ahead with that.

Comment: Is there anything else I can help you regarding this issue?